Trying to get the width/height of the element in react
I was trying to get the width/height of the div in react but when I print the value it says undefined at first in console but if I make some changes in the code (not changing the whole code but instead doing something like removing a semi colon or adding semi colon) and then press ctrl + s in vs code then the value gets printed in console, i tried adding a set time function to delay the function call but still first i get undefined
const [circleWidth, setcircleWidth] = useState();
    
    const getWidth = () => {
        const element = document.querySelector(".testimonial-circle-left");
        const positionInfo = element.getBoundingClientRect(0);
        let width = positionInfo.width;
        setcircleWidth(width);
        console.log(circleWidth);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getWidth();
    }, []);

here I am using offsetWidth/offsetHeight but it's not working so when I use getBoundingClientRect after seeing another post in stackoverflow it gave the answer but the main issue was the problem mentioned above.

circleWidth is being logged before the state is updated. setcircleWidth does not immediately update the value of the state, it just schedules the update, which happens after the current rendering cycle. So when you call console.log(circleWidth), it logs the old value of circleWidth rather than the new one.

You are logging the circleWidth before the state is updated. You have two methods.

Assign 0 to circleWidth and setCircleWidth to use it in another place.
If you want to use circleWidth in the same function then use width instead.

const getWidth = useCallback(() => {
        const element = document.querySelector(".testimonial-circle-left")
        const positionInfo = element.getBoundingClientRect(0)
        let width = positionInfo.width
        setCircleWidth(width)
        console.log(circleWidth) // React takes some millisecond to update state
        console.log(width) // Use width if you want to perform some operation here
    }, [circleWidth])

Other method using useRef:
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"

function App() {
    const [circleWidth, setCircleWidth] = useState(0)
    const divRef = useRef(null)

    const getWidth = useCallback(() => {
        const element = document.querySelector(".testimonial-circle-left")
        const positionInfo = element.getBoundingClientRect(0)
        let width = positionInfo.width
        setCircleWidth(width)
        console.log(circleWidth) // React takes some millisecond to update state
        console.log(width) // Use width if you want to perform some operation here
    }, [circleWidth])

    const getWidthByRef = () => {
        if (!divRef.current) return 0

        const width = divRef.current?.getBoundingClientRect(0).width
        console.log("Using Ref " + width)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getWidth()
        getWidthByRef()
    }, [getWidth])

    return (
        <div
            style={{ width: "600px", height: "800px", backgroundColor: "lightgreen" }}
            ref={divRef}
            className="testimonial-circle-left"
        ></div>
    )
}
export default App

